# Nodejs Cassandra Client [node-cassandra-client]

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I tried connecting to my cassandra cluster [version 1.0.6] via nodejs using [node-cassandra-client](https://github.com/racker/node-cassandra-client)

This is my sample script

```
var Connection = require('cassandra-client').Connection;
var con = new Connection({host:'x.x.x.x', port:9160, keyspace:'Stats', timeout:10000});
console.log(con);
con.execute('UPDATE TestCF ?=? WHERE key=?', ['cola', '1', '20120132'], function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Failed");
    } else {
        console.log("success");
    }
});
```

On executing the script

```
    The "sys" module is now called "util". It should have a similar interface.
    node-cassandra-client.driver: connecting x.x.x.x:9160 {}
    { validators: {},
      client: null,
      connectionInfo: 
       { host: 'x.x.x.x',
         port: 9160,
         keyspace: 'Stats',
         timeout: 10000 },
      timeout: 10000 }

    node.js:201
            throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
                  ^
    TypeError: Cannot call method 'execute_cql_query' of null
        at [object Object].execute (/home/tamil/workspace/TestProjects/node-cass/node_modules/cassandra-client/lib/driver.js:367:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/tamil/workspace/TestProjects/node-cass/index.js:5:5)
        at Module._compile (module.js:432:26)
        at Object..js (module.js:450:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:351:31)
        at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
        at Array.0 (module.js:470:10)
        at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

My nodetool stats

```
Address         DC          Rack        Status State   Load            Owns    Token                                       
x.x.x.x         datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  1.03 MB         100.00% 0
```

What would be the error reason? and Need some help to fix this

Comment: FYI executing the same query when executed with pooled connection worked

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the client inside your connection is null.  You need to connect() first.  Here's an example (ignores all errors):

```
var con = new Connection({host:'x.x.x.x', port:9160, keyspace:'Stats', timeout:10000});
con.connect(function(err) {
  assert.ifError(err);
  con.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestCF', [], function(err, rows) {
    con.close(function(err) {
      // you're done now.
    });
  });
});
```

I recommend using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to handle the ordering of connct, query, close, etc.

Comment: How are you handling the ordering of connect, query and close with async?

Comment: anything that guarantees an in-order workflow: async.series and async.waterfall come to mind.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some kind of problem with the node.js thrift driver. I've had more luck with [Helenus](https://github.com/simplereach/helenus).